# Creating one graph from two or more different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I'm in the process of creating a macro which creates an xy graph from data chosen using input boxes. I've run into two problems (one major and one minor).

1. I am given an error message whenever I try to select data from a different worksheet. How can I make the macro able to use data from several different worksheets? (I suspect that the problem is under the comment, "Set additional y values with input box", but I'm not sure)
   The error message is "Run-time error 1004: Selection method of range class failed", and it refers to the line

```
myAddTitle.OFFEST(1, 0).Select
```

after I try to select data from a new worksheet for my second series.

2. No matter what I set as the name for series 1, the legend always says Series 1. How can i make it correspond to myYTitle?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

'''

```
Sub InsertFSC()
'
'
'
'
`With ActiveSheet
'
' Set x values with input box
Dim myXCell As Range
Dim myXSeries As Range
Dim myXTitle As Range
Set myXTitle = Application.InputBox("Please select the heading of the column which contains 
your desired X values:", "Select title cell", Type:=8)
myXTitle.OFFSET(1, 0).Select
Set myXCell = Selection
Range(myXCell, myXCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Set myXSeries = Selection
'
'
' Set y values with input box
Dim myYCell As Range
Dim myYSeries As Range
Dim myYTitle As Range
Set myYTitle = Application.InputBox("Please select the heading of the column which contains your desired Y values:", "Select title cell", Type:=8)
myYTitle.OFFSET(1, 0).Select
Set myYCell = Selection
Range(myYCell, myYCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Set myYSeries = Selection
'
'
' Create Blank Graph
Dim chartObj As ChartObject
Dim DataChart As Chart
Set chartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=10, Left:=325, Width:=600, Height:=300)
Set DataChart = chartObj.Chart
DataChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
'
'
' Remove auto-plotted data
Do While DataChart.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
DataChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Loop
'
'
' Add first data series
With DataChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = myYTitle
    .XValues = myXSeries
    .Values = myYSeries
End With
'
'
'
' Formatting
' Display a message box with yes/no and question icon - want to continue?
If MsgBox("Would you like to add another Y data series to your graph?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Continue?") = vbYes Then
     MsgBox "The user clicked Yes"
'
'
'
' BEGIN THE LOOP of selecting additional Y values until user selects NO
Do Until answer = vbNo
'
' Set additional y values with input box
Dim myAddCell As Range
Dim myAddSeries As Range
Dim myAddTitle As Range
Set myAddTitle = Application.InputBox("Please select the heading of the column which contains the Y values you want to add:", "Select title cell", Type:=8)
myAddTitle.OFFSET(1, 0).Select
Set myAddCell = Selection
Range(myAddCell, myAddCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Set myAddSeries = Selection
'
'
' Add the new data to graph
With DataChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   .Name = myAddTitle
   .XValues = myXSeries
   .Values = myAddSeries
End With
'
'
' Display message box with yes/no and question icon
answer = MsgBox("Would you like to continue and select another Y data series?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Continue?")
' END OF LOOP
Loop
Else
     MsgBox "The user clicked No"
End If
'
'
'
' Add a chart title and axis labels with input box
With DataChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = Application.InputBox("Please enter a chart title", "Chart Title Name", Type:=2)
' Add X Axis title
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = myXTitle
' Add Y Axis title with input box?
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Application.InputBox("Please enter the Y axis title", "Y axis Name", Type:=2)
End With
'
'
End With
End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Did you try Tim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520709/9245853) yet?

Comment: "I am given an error message" is not a useful description of exactly what happens when you run your code. Please always include exact error message(s) and the code line(s) which raise those errors.

Comment: I did try Tim's answer, which I greatly appreciated! However, while it absolutely made the code cleaner, the name of the series remained as "Series 1". (Thank you for your patience, as I am new to this forum!) :)

Comment: You could have commented to note that on my original answer, and I could have tried to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub InsertFSC()

    Dim xVals As Range, yVals As Range, allYVals As Collection
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim DataChart As Chart
    
    Set allYVals = New Collection
    
    Set xVals = GetRange("Please select the heading of the column which contains your desired X values:")
    If xVals Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'cancelled xvals selection
    'loop and collect Yvalue column(s)
    Do
        Set yVals = GetRange("Please select Y values column header (or cancel if done):")
        If Not yVals Is Nothing Then
            allYVals.Add yVals
        Else
            Exit Do 'user is done selecting
        End If
    Loop
    
    If allYVals.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub 'didn't get any yvalues selected
    
    'add the chart
    Set chartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=10, Left:=325, Width:=600, Height:=300)
    Set DataChart = chartObj.Chart
    DataChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth

    ' Remove auto-plotted data
    Do While DataChart.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
        DataChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
    'loop over the collected y values ranges and add a series for each one
    For Each yVals In allYVals
        With DataChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
           .Name = yVals.Cells(1).Value
           .XValues = xVals.Offset(1, 0).Resize(xVals.Rows.Count - 1) 'move/resize to exclude header
           .Values = yVals.Offset(1, 0).Resize(xVals.Rows.Count - 1)
        End With
    Next
End Sub

'return a user-selected range or Nothing
Function GetRange(msg As String)
    Dim rv As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rv = Application.InputBox(msg, "Select title cell", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rv Is Nothing Then
        Set rv = rv.Parent.Range(rv, rv.End(xlDown))
    End If
    Set GetRange = rv
End Function
```

If this is for general use, you should add some checks on the user-selected ranges - eg. make sure the range is not empty, only one column is selected, that the range doesn't span an entire column (or does not exceed some sensible size limit), and that the X and Y ranges are the same size.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!